# Struts 2 Tag inside DisplayTag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I want to insert Struts2 tag inside display tag

**Display Tag:**

```jsp
<display:column
    title="Number of Requests"
    property="quantity" format="{0,number,###,##0}"
    sortable="true" defaultorder="descending"
    class="OBDataBorderBar" style="text-align:right;"
    headerClass="OBDataHeaderBarSortLeft"
    href="ProdLinkIncl.action?Page=2301"
    paramId="prodNameLink" paramProperty="layer"
    total="true" />
```

I want to insert this tag inside title="Number of Requests":

```jsp
<s:text name="NumberofRequests">
<s:property value="%{getText('ApplicationResources_fr.NumberofRequests')}"/></s:text>
```

Comment: what prevents you from that?

Comment: its showing error in jsp  - EL Syntax Error 
 - Undefined attribute name 
  "NumberofRequests"
 - No end tag (</
  display:column>).
 - Encountered "<" at line 1, 
  column 1.

Comment: you can use only one tag

Comment: I have requirement to read title value dynamically from properties file thats why I want this.

Comment: It looks like do you want to get the text from the other resource bundle not used by the action?

Comment: yes exactly, I want it from resource bundle